# Beta: Error reading Beta build properties

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

get this bug on startup of my application, but only on Android Studio 2.2.0. on my machine. Everything is up-to-date and this error occurs only on my machine. App is not crasing, but leaves this stactrace:

```
E/Beta: Error reading Beta build properties
java.io.FileNotFoundException: crashlytics-build.properties
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:339)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
at com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta.loadBuildProperties(Beta.java:172)
at com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta.doInBackground(Beta.java:75)
at com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta.doInBackground(Beta.java:30)
at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that's because you have:

```
ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

In your application build.gradle file.

Comment: if this is set to false Crashlytics will  think you havent integrated it into your app and will prompt you to sign up .

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Crashlytics for debug builds when initializing:

```
    // Set up Crashlytics, disabled for debug builds
    Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build();

    // Initialize Fabric with the debug-disabled crashlytics.
    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

Comment: This will disable crashlytics at runtime. You will also need to add, "ext.enableCrashlytics = false" to your app build.gradle. See: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html